# How to limit keyword highlighting when they appear in variable names

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I imported a custom language for PL/SQL into Notepad++, and I'm trying to fine-tune the syntax highlighting. I've enabled code folding for multi-line comments, and changed the background colour on many styles.
What I can't figure out is, how to prevent the keyword "IF" in the procedure name "VERIFY_CHANGES()" from being high-lighted as a keyword.
Another example is the keyword "END" is being high-lighted in the variable name "V_END_DATE".

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL is fairly hard to parse properly. [Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files) uses [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/), which does this in about 900 lines of code — and special-cases `if` just to get that far. Looking at the [configuration file,](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/userDefineLang_plsql.xml) there is no mention of user-variable — only *keywords*.

It would require some improvements to Scintilla to handle this syntax as you want.